# Application Insights service unable to fetch metrics from On-premises server

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, on-premises-instances

Cloud Type – Azure

Service – Application Insights service

Problem type – help needed for implementation of Azure Insights service (SaaS based service) on hybrid environment (on premise to cloud).

Detailed Problem Statement – Azure Application Insights service capture lot of performance and execution  related parameters on target server and build sophisticated modelling, log analytics and insights services on top of this data. Azure documentation of this service states that this service’s agent (Called as App Insights MV2) can also be deployed on premise servers and it can send data for ASP.NET/.NET Core applications from ‘on premise’ servers to Azure service through HTTP protocol.

tried to install this agent on one of the on-premise servers of client environment as per instructions mentioned in this site. Application Insights agent was successfully installed and registered with corresponding cloud services (based on provided connection string). The status of App Insights monitoring on ‘On premise’ server showed running status but there was no metric observed under ‘Live metrics’ or log analytics on cloud portal. On through investigation it is concluded that even though agent register itself successfully, it is not sending metric and monitoring information to Application Insights cloud service.

We need help in analysing the problem and rectifying it so that ‘On premise’ server information can be captured on application insights and similar level of services will be available for ‘on premises’ server.

Comment: Please post the link to the docs you are referring to.

Comment: @PeterBons https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/status-monitor-v2-get-started

Comment: It should work. If it doesn't it might be a good idea to open a support ticket.